# Assembly JE not jumping after CMP

Tags: assembly, gdb

I have the following code snippet thats causing me issues.

```
0x0000000000401556 <+56>:   cmp    $0x37,%edx
0x0000000000401559 <+59>:   je     0x401560 <phase_5+66>
0x000000000040155b <+61>:   callq  0x401a64 <do_not_come_here>
0x0000000000401560 <+66>:   pop    %rbx
0x0000000000401561 <+67>:   retq
```

and here is part of the registers status on line +59, right before it either jumps or not.

```
rax            0x6  6
rbx            0x6d97c0 7182272
rcx            0x3  3
rdx            0x21 37
rsi            0x6d97c0 7182272
rdi            0x6d97c6 7182278
```

Now obviously we want to jump over to line +66 and return. However, despite the fact that

```
%rdx = 37 (hence %edx=37),
```

the code doesn't jump and falls into "do_not_come_here". 
My gdb reports that at the moment of jump, the flags that were set were

```
eflags         0x297    [ CF PF AF SF IF ]
```

I don't even have the ZF flag in there. What is going on? Please help me.

Comment: The order is not a problem here. When I have my breakpoint at <+56> the next step leads me to <+59> and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Oops. My mistake. $0x37 is not the same as 37, and I was completely fooled.